# Python script to run a visual studio C++ program multiple time with different arguments

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a C++ Visual Studio program called Test which takes two arguments. I have to run this program with large number of different arguments like:

- **./test  -a  -b (a is arg1, b is arg2)**
- **./test  -c  -d**
- .
- .
- .

How can I create a python script which runs this program multiple times if I provide the set of arguments? (instead of me running the above command multiple times).

**Soln:**
This is the code I used:

```
for commands in listargs:
    cmd = ["../../Test.exe", commands[0], commands[1]]
    result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdin, stderr = result.communicate()
    print stdin
```

I am giving the arguments in a list of 2-member tuples(listargs). Each tuple has the arguments for one execution. Or as **abernet** mentioned, we can give arguments in csv file. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: What do you mean by "c++ visual studio program"? Do you just mean an executable (which you happen to have compiled with Visual Studio's C++ compiler)?

Comment: More importantly, how do you want to provide the set of arguments? Do you want to type in `a` and `b` at a prompt? Or create a CSV file with rows like `a,b`? Or …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of stuff, you should use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/lib/module-subprocess.html), possibly `subprocess.communicate`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['./test', '-' + a, '-' + b])
p.communicate()
```

This is a very versatile command that will also allow you to redirect inputs and outputs. See [PMOTW](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained how you want to "provide the set of arguments".

Let's say you want to create a CSV file, like this:

```
a,b
c,d
```

That's nice and simple to create in a text editor, or you can even do it in Excel.

Python has a [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module in the standard library that knows how to read exactly that format, turning each line into a list of values.

And it has a [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module that knows how to run a program with a list of arguments.

So, for example:

```
with open('args.csv') as f:
    for args in csv.reader(f):
        subprocess.call(['./test'] + args)
```

If you want to store the output of each run in a file, or check the output and raise an exception on errors, etc., you can do almost anything you want with `subprocess`, you just have to read the docs.